# Images on Embed Messages

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I have problems with adding an image to the embed message, it is not a particular image but it takes the name of a list and shows the corresponding image if I use a normal channel.send message there is no problem, but when adding it to the embed, I need to use URL or setImage. Either the image is not displayed or gives errors about a String, among other errors.

[Discord Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgKU6.png)

[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkWKh.png)

[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmzwm.png)

The commented message at the end does not give me a problem and shows the image, obviously outside the embed

Comment: Don't post code as images, [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```js
image: { file: [`attachment://Digimons/${img}`] }
```